# Oracle BI post-installation issues on Windows Server 2012

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-bi

I have installed Oracle BI and oracle 11g Database on Windows Server 2012 (physical machine).
Despite an initial error regarding OS certification, the installation completes successfully with all the Oracle BI components. But after this, the following issues arise:

1. Oracle BI Administration Tool does not show up after executing either BI Administration or directly firing admintool.exe under Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\server\bin
2. I'm not able to log-in in OBIEE but after restarting Oracle BI services, this is feasible.
3. When I log-in in OBIEE I cannot create new analysis or dashboard. After clicking 'New Analysis' or 'New Dashboard' no pop-up panel shows up.

Does anyone have any clue about any of the above?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to all aforementioned issues was to set up Oracle BI as specs recommend to Windows Server 2008 R2 with the correct version of Java. After this none of the above problems occurred.

Answer (score -1):

For number 3, unable to create a new analysis or dashboard, the issue may be related to your browser. Using Firefox instead of Chrome fixed the issue for me. For number 1, the administration tool worked for me, but did take a very long time to open.